# Dynamic data table component, using Angular, not displaying data

Tags: angular, mat-table, dynamic-tables

I'm currently learning Angular.
I'm creating a table component that I could reuse throughout my app.

I can set the columns and pagination information. It displays correctly.

My problem is that I could not get the data to display on the table.

[image: sample output]

Can you help me identify what I did wrong here?

Here's how I'm using the component.

```
<app-data-table [tableDataSource] ="tableDataSrc" 
  [tableColumns]="tableCols"
  [pageSize]= "pageSize"
  [pageSizes] = "pageSizes"
  [totalPages]="totalItems">
</app-data-table>
```

Here's the data-table-component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSrc" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableCols">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ col }}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col | titlecase }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile"> {{profile[col]}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableCols"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableCols;"></tr>
</table>
```

And here's the data-table-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  // input data source
  tableDataSrc : any;
  @Input('tableDataSource') tableData: {}[];

  // input columns
  @Input('tableColumns') tableCols: string[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  
  // input for pagination
  @Input('page') page = 1;
  @Input('count') count = 0;
  @Input('pageSize') pageSize = 10;
  @Input('pageSizes') pageSizes = [10, 25, 50, 100, 150];
  @Input('totalPages') totalItems : number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("table data: " + this.tableData);
    
    this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  refresh() {

  }

  onPaginate(pageEvent: PageEvent)  {
    this.page = pageEvent.pageIndex;
    this.pageSize = pageEvent.pageSize;
    this.refresh();
  }
}
```

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: `tableCols` is array of a string and in your code is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the proble.

on my data-table-component.ts

I changed this line

```
// input data source
tableDataSrc : any;
@Input('tableDataSource') tableData: {}[];
```

to this line

```
@Input('tableDataSource') tableDataSource : any;
```